# How to delete projects and add bigquery-public-data project on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-public-datasets

I have already some projects on Google BigQuery console. I need to delete them and add a bigquery-public-data dataset for my exercises. I am still learning data analytics on Coursera. Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a project in the BigQuery console, select the project in the Explorer pane then do one of the following:

- Click `View actions` > `Open`, then click `UNPIN PORJECT` button placed in the upper right corner of the screen.
- Click the pin logo beside the project ID you want to remove.

To add `bigquery-public-data` project in your BigQuery console:

1. Enter this URL in your browser:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=bigquery-public-data&page=project
```

2. Select your project in the GCP console to switch back to your own project and verify if the `bigquery-public-data` project has been pinned in the BQ console.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It works!